# Asynchronously function returns undefined with $q deferred

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am calling my data from my api through a factory that looks like this:

```
app.factory('Service', ['$http', function ($http) {

var urlBase = 'http://localhost:50476/api';
var Service = {};

Service.getComp = function () {
    return $http.get(urlBase + '/complaints')

};

return Service;
}]);
```

Then I use my controller to use the directive:

```
getComp();
$scope.comp = [];

function getComp() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Service.getComp()
    .success(function (comp) {
        console.log('comp', comp); //returns array data
        $scope.comp = comp.data;
        deferred.resolve(comp);
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.error = 'error' + error.message;
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

$scope.index = 0;
$scope.complaints = $scope.comp[0];
console.log($scope.complaints); //undefined
console.log($scope.comp); //array of 0
```

When I try to access the items outside of the function it is undefined. I tried to look for resolutions like using $q but it is still not displaying data. When I added the deferred part my ng-repeat stops working as well.

Comment: at the time you log $scope.complaints it is undefined because the response from the $http request hasn't returned yet, so your 'success' method hasn't executed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getComp();
$scope.comp = [];

function getComp() {
    return Service.getComp()
    .success(function (comp) {
        $scope.comp = comp.data;
        $scope.complaints = $scope.comp[0];
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.error = 'error' + error.message;
    });
}
```

The values are undefined when you do your logs because those lines run before your request comes back from the server. That's why setting `$scope.complaints` has to go into the `success` callback.

Comment: Million thanks. I been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure `complaints` are loaded on certain states before you start your logic you can use ui-routers [`resolve` keyword](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) (i suppose you are using ui-router with ionic - standard package)

In you main.js

```
$stateProvider.state('yourState', {
  resolve: {
    complaints: function(Service) {
      return Service.getComp();
    }
  }
});
```

in your controller you can then inject `complaints`

```
.controller('myController', function(complaints) {
   $scope.complaints = complaints;
})
```

`resolve` at $stateProvider will block and wait for the promise to resolve...